# How to set the Header to the UICollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionreusableview

I want to set the default section header to the `UICollectionView`.I used the below code,it crashed.

In `-viewDidLoad`

```
[feedcollectionview registerClass:[UICollectionReusableView class] forSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader withReuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
```

In `-viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind`

```
UICollectionReusableView *reusableview = nil;
  if (kind == UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader) {
        UICollectionReusableView *headerView = [collectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader withReuseIdentifier:@"HeaderView" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        [headerView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];        
        reusableview=headerView;
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

in ViewDidLoad Identifier not same viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind
you must choose @"cell"  or @"HeaderView"